# Android App crashed on pressing signup button

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have tried to create an login and registration form in VS Code with firebase Authentication service. So i added firebase dependencies to the build gradle and run the app, When i click the login or register button ,Data base updated with data but the app crashes. Also No error log on terminal.
Please some one help me out as i am stuck here since a week and did almost everything what i can.
Will be greatfull for your kind support
This is my Signup page code

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { View, Text,Image,StyleSheet,KeyboardAvoidingView,TouchableOpacity,Alert} from 'react-native'
import {TextInput,Button} from 'react-native-paper'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';


const Loginscreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [email,setemail]=useState('')
    const [password,setpassword]=useState('')
    const userSignup=async ()=>{
        if(!email||!password)
        {Alert.alert('Email or password is missing !')
    return
    }
    try{
        await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)    
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        Alert.alert('Failure !')
    }
    
    }
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='position'>
        <View style={styles.box_1}>
         <Image style={{width:200,height:200}} source={require('../assets/logo.png')} />
        <Text style={styles.loginmessage}>
            Please Sign Up to Continue...
        </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.box_2}>
        <TextInput label='Email'
         value={email} 
         mode='outlined'
         onChangeText={text=>setemail(text)}/>
         <TextInput label='Password'
         value={password}
         mode='outlined'
         secureTextEntry={true}
         onChangeText={text=>setpassword(text)}
         
         />
          <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => userSignup()}>
    Sign Up
  </Button>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Login')}><Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Log In ?</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}
```

This is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/**
 * Architectures to build native code for.
 */
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.olxfirebase"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()

        if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
            // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-21",
                        "APP_STL=c++_shared",
                        "NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang",
                        "GENERATED_SRC_DIR=$buildDir/generated/source",
                        "PROJECT_BUILD_DIR=$buildDir",
                        "REACT_ANDROID_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid",
                        "REACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build"
                    cFlags "-Wall", "-Werror", "-fexceptions", "-frtti", "-DWITH_INSPECTOR=1"
                    cppFlags "-std=c++17"
                    // Make sure this target name is the same you specify inside the
                    // src/main/jni/Android.mk file for the `LOCAL_MODULE` variable.
                    targets "olxfirebase_appmodules"

                    // Fix for windows limit on number of character in file paths and in command lines
                    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                        arguments "NDK_OUT=${rootProject.projectDir.getParent()}\\.cxx",
                            "NDK_APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=true"
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
        // We configure the NDK build only if you decide to opt-in for the New Architecture.
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path "$projectDir/src/main/jni/Android.mk"
            }
        }
        def reactAndroidProjectDir = project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir
        def packageReactNdkDebugLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkDebugLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkDebugLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        def packageReactNdkReleaseLibs = tasks.register("packageReactNdkReleaseLibs", Copy) {
            dependsOn(":ReactAndroid:packageReactNdkReleaseLibsForBuck")
            from("$reactAndroidProjectDir/src/main/jni/prebuilt/lib")
            into("$buildDir/react-ndk/exported")
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            // If you wish to add a custom TurboModule or component locally,
            // you should uncomment this line.
            // preBuild.dependsOn("generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema")
            preDebugBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkDebugLibs)
            preReleaseBuild.dependsOn(packageReactNdkReleaseLibs)

            // Due to a bug inside AGP, we have to explicitly set a dependency
            // between configureNdkBuild* tasks and the preBuild tasks.
            // This can be removed once this is solved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207403732
            configureNdkBuildRelease.dependsOn(preReleaseBuild)
            configureNdkBuildDebug.dependsOn(preDebugBuild)
            reactNativeArchitectures().each { architecture ->
                tasks.findByName("configureNdkBuildDebug[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preDebugBuild")
                }
                tasks.findByName("configureNdkBuildRelease[${architecture}]")?.configure {
                    dependsOn("preReleaseBuild")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
     implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"



    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    // If new architecture is enabled, we let you build RN from source
    // Otherwise we fallback to a prebuilt .aar bundled in the NPM package.
    // This will be applied to all the imported transtitive dependency.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native"))
                    .using(project(":ReactAndroid")).because("On New Architecture we're building React Native from source")
        }
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    // To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
    // - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
    // - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
    // - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
    return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}
```

this is my Project-level Build.Gradle Code

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            // For Android Users, we need to use NDK 23, otherwise the build will
            // fail due to paths longer than the OS limit
            ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also share the message appear while crashing  and also please verify you have cadded googlejson.service file in correct folder . Added correct dependencies of firebase .

Comment: You may be looking for the stacktrace in the wrong place; please provide logcat (presumably this may be NPE anyway, which means being duplicate of a canonical answer).

Comment: When responding to a other user here on SO, you can get their attention and let them know you responded by including their name in your reply. Like @Jay will notify me you responded.

Comment: Dear @Jagroop, message appeared is "olxfirebase has Stopped " (olxfirebase is application name)

Comment: Try console.log('err', err) in your catch and also watch the stack trace on android studio if the app crashed due to the native side of things it will show up there. It might be the firebase setup something is missing or some version mismatch or not matching as needed.

Comment: @MandipGiri not solved yet 